# Swift not recognizing classes of installed SPM packages

Tags: swift, xcode, algolia, swift-package-manager

I have imported Algolia's InstantSearch into my project. All Algolia classes (which are declared as public in the packages) aren't being recognized in the Swift files. I remembered to import InstantSearch in all files.

One of the error messages:

```
Cannot find type 'QueryInputObservableController' in scope
```

The respective line of code:

```
@ObservedObject var queryInputController: QueryInputObservableController
```

I'm not getting this issue from any other imported packages.

Answer (score -2):

did you install the pods, Flow the instruction to add cocopods. https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/installation/ios/

Create / Update your pod file.

```
pod 'InstantSearch', '~> 7.1'
```

then open terminal and run

> 'pod install'

then open .xcworkspace.

Comment: he is asking about SPM ... how pods relative to the question ?

Comment: @JawadAli QueryInputObservableController  he is trying to inherit is from ' Instant search pod'.  Please explain how it's not related?

Comment: A package is not a pod, if you read the page you linked to you see it can be installed using swift package manager

Comment: @JoakimDanielson what if he is not using package manager and uses cocopods. How will the project know there is a VC called QueryInputObservableController? 

package manager also he need to install..

Comment: Then why does the title of the question say SPM packages and why does it have a spm tag? There is no logic to what you are saying.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm not using Cocoapods in any part of my project. I'm using Swift Package Manager.